# How to add confining potentials in PySCF?

Tags: model-hamiltonians, pyscf

I want to try to model the electornic structure of atoms in a confining potential, eg. add a term to the Hamiltonian either of a constant value $V$ after certain distance from the origin or just the form $r^n$.

I've came across [this example](https://github.com/pyscf/pyscf.github.io/blob/master/examples/scf/40-apply_electric_field.py) which adds an electric field to the molecule, and it is done using an extra term of the form $E r$ as

```
def apply_field(E):
    mol.set_common_orig([0, 0, 0])  # The gauge origin for dipole integral
    h =(mol.intor('cint1e_kin_sph') + mol.intor('cint1e_nuc_sph') + numpy.einsum('x,xij->ij', E, mol.intor('cint1e_r_sph', comp=3)))
    mf = scf.UHF(mol)
```

This led to me understanding that there's a [set of integrals](https://github.com/pyscf/pyscf/blob/master/pyscf/gto/moleintor.py) that can be more or less directly added to the Hamiltonian (after taking care of the dimension issues I assume). However this list is rather limited and I am not sure how to add either an $r^n$ term or a step function term - is there something that I can do to add a general operator?

**Edit:** I assume it comes down to the fact that I should cast a specific operator onto the basis in which the Hamiltonian is written. Is there a nice way of doing this?